# Subclassing PFUser in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, pfuser

I am trying to subclass the PFUser for one of my applications. I know how to do it in Objective C, but have not been able to get it to work in Swift. The parse documentation does not provide info on how to subclass PFUser. I am using Version 7.0 beta 6.

Here is my attempt: For some reason it doesn't like PFSubclassing, or the load() function and property declarations. I have included the following in my bridge header file:

Header File

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

---

```
import Parse
import Foundation



class User : PFUser, PFSubclassing {

    override class func load() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "User"
    }

    //My variables
    dynamic var firstname: String
    dynamic var lastname: String

}
```

Comment: You don't need to implement parseClassName() since PFUser already implements this one.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0, PFSubclassing is unnecessary when subclassing with PFUser.

Delete PFSubclassing and you are good to go!